# How do I access an array in an array of class instances?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, tableview

I'm trying to practice making list apps with models by making a class to represent each list item.  I have a Category class which contains three properties - two strings and one array of strings.  Here is the class:

```
class Category {

var name: String
var emoji: String
var topics: [String]
   // (the getCategories method listed below goes here) //  

init(name: String, emoji: String, topics: [String]) {
   self.name = name
   self.emoji = emoji
   self.topics = topics 
}
```

In my Category class I have a method to assign values to the categories so I can keep them out of the view controller.  This method is listed below:

```
class func getCategories() -> [Category]
    {
        let categories = [Category(name:"cat", emoji:"", topics: ["paws","tails", "fur", "pussyfoot","purr", "kitten", "meow"])
    ]
     return categories
}
```

In one of my tableview controller files I am trying to get the number of rows in section by setting it to the count of the topics from the topics in the getCategories method.  Nothing I do seems to work, although I am able to get the count of the categories in the getCategories method...I just seem to be unable to access the topics array specifically.

Here's what I did to get the categories count...

```
    var categories = Category.getCategories()
     .... 
            override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
```

I need to do this except I need to get the count of the topics that I set in the getCategories method.

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: `return categories[section].topics.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece I think you are missing is that you need to know which section you want to get the topic count from. This should be provided to you in some why by the table view datasource callback.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories[section].topics.count
}
```

In addition, when you need to access a specific topic, you will be passed an `indexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let topic = categories[indexPath.section].topics[indexPath.row]
    let cell = …
    …
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `categories` is an array of `Category` objects, you need to access the correct index, then the topics array and get the count:

```
categories[section].topics.count
```